# Two default gateways with different metric on CentOS 7 box - how?

Tags: centos, routing, gateway, metric

I'm begging for help here. Been spending hours researching how to solve what seemed like a simple problem:

On a CentOS 7.6 host with two network interfaces on two different networks, how to have two default gateways with a set metric to favour one of these interfaces. Can't do it. Would anybody please tell me what I'm missing before I have no hair left?

- First, I've tried using the `METRIC=xxx` setting in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts-/ifcfg-<interface>` files based on some advice found on the web. Obviously if that ever was supported, it's no longer. Next.
- Then I've tried using policy-based routing following the tons of documentation that can be found online. Unfortunately very few mention adding metric values.

So, the full details (sorry it's long but I don't want to skip anything):

- This machine has two active interfaces `enp10s4f0` (IP `10.149.247.23`, prefix `/24`) and `enp2s0f0` (IP `10.149.160.21`, prefix `/24`).
- It has two gateways: `10.149.247.254` and `10.149.160.254`. I want `10.149.160.254` to be the "best" gateway, therefore with the lower metric.
  I also want to avoid asymetric routing.
- I can reach my goal of having different metrics on gateways by means of entering routes with

  ```
  ip route add default ... dev ... metric
  ```

  but I want it to be persistent.
- So I've created two routing tables in `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`:

  ```
  247 enp10s4f0table  
  160 enp2s0f0table
  ```

  And I've made the following rule and route files in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`:

  ```
  route-enp10s4f0:  
  10.149.247.0/24 dev enp10s4f0 src 10.149.247.23 table enp10s4f0table  
  default via 10.149.247.254 dev enp10s4f0 metric 110 table enp10s4f0table  

  rule-enp10s4f0:  
  from 10.149.247.23/32 table enp10s4f0table
  to 10.149.247.23 table enp10s4f0table  

  route-enp2s0f0:  
  10.149.160.0/24 dev enp2s0f0 src 10.149.160.21 table enp2s0f0table  
  default via 10.149.160.254 dev enp2s0f0 table enp2s0f0table  

  rule-enp2s0f0:  
  from 10.149.160.21/32 table enp2s0f0table
  to 10.149.160.21 table enp2s0f0table
  ```
- Then I've used the proper incantations:

  ```
  yum install NetworkManager-config-routing-rules  
  systemctl enable NetworkManager-dispatcher.service  
  systemctl start NetworkManager-dispatcher.service
  ```

  ... and reboot.

Obviously the configuration is read and processed properly but the metric is *not* applied to the `10.149.247.254` gateway:

```
# ip route show table enp10s4f0table
default via 10.149.247.254 dev enp10s4f0 metric 110
10.149.247.0/24 dev enp10s4f0 scope link src 10.149.247.23  
# ip route show table enp2s0f0table
default via 10.149.160.254 dev enp2s0f0  
# ip rule show
0: from all lookup local
32762: from all to 10.149.160.21 lookup enp2s0f0table
32763: from 10.149.160.21 lookup enp2s0f0table
32764: from all to 10.149.247.23 lookup enp10s4f0table
32765: from 10.149.247.23 lookup enp10s4f0table
32766: from all lookup main
32767: from all lookup default
```

But:

```
# ip route show
default via 10.149.247.254 dev enp10s4f0 proto static metric 100
default via 10.149.160.254 dev enp2s0f0 proto static metric 102
10.149.160.0/24 dev enp2s0f0 proto kernel scope link src 
10.149.160.21 metric 102
10.149.247.0/24 dev enp10s4f0 proto kernel scope link src 
10.149.247.23 metric 100
192.168.2.0/24 dev enp10s4f1 proto kernel scope link src 
192.168.2.14 metric 101
```

[OK, I do have a third interface `enp10s4f1` but this one has `DEFROUTE=no` and no `GATEWAY=` in its `ifcfg` file so I haven't mentioned it so far]

See?

- No metric 110 on the `default via 10.149.247.254 dev enp10s4f0...` line.
- And the result is the exact opposite to what I'm trying to achieve: `enp10s4f0`'s default gateway has a lower metric than `enp2s0f0`'s

I can confirm this by tracerouting to a host outside of these two networks, packets do get out through `10.149.247.254`

I'm stuck at this point. Can't figure it out. Please kindly help if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
IPV4_ROUTE_METRIC=xxx
```

in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts-/ifcfg-interface` file.

I had the same problem in a Centos 7 box; after some googling, I found this setting and got it to work across reboots.